# Why was this question closed as "off-topic"?

Tags: discussion

I posted [this question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/64168/is-there-any-evidence-of-torture-at-the-nuremberg-trials) that as been hastly closed without anyone providing any comment with the following statement:

> The primary purpose of this question appears to be to promote or
> discredit a specific idea, theory, cause, group or person. It does not
> appear to be a good-faith effort to learn more about history as
> defined in the help centre.

I'm not discrediting nothing or anyone in my question, I was simply presented with informations and sources regarding a specific fact. After a long research I am unable to determine an answer to the question in particular the last source I mentioned seems to look solid and from a valid author, so I was asking if someone better informed than me could provide an answer.

I'm not a Holocaust denier, I'm not a Nazi sympathizer and I'm not questioning the Nuremberg Trials. I'm only looking for an answer.

I submitted for reopen with no luck, so I'm looking for clues for why it has been closed.

Comment: @justCal I included my research on the question to be the most complete as possible, I'm not pushing any agenda. I will edit my question to include only the last source given, the one that is written by a solid author and see if I can get an answer

Comment: If I make up some utter BS about aliens, that doesn't need to be included in your question for completeness' sake either. In fact, doing so would be giving it publicity it hasn't earned on its own merits. The question would be plenty complete without it. Thus the only logical rationale for including it would be in order to help promote my wacked-out theory about aliens.

Comment: @T.E.D. Ok, my fault, I've edited the question to only include the only source that seems solid and from a valid an recognized author.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be aware that this site, due to unrelenting bad-faith trolling by white supremacists, has been forced to implement a [much higher standard for questions about or adjacent to the Holocaust](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3683/site-policy-for-very-heavily-trolled-topics).

> **Questions on these topics have a hair-trigger for being put on hold.
> This goes in particular for new users who don't have a proven
> track-record of asking good questions.**

I'd encourage reading the entire question and its answers.

The "promote or discredit" wording is the custom close reason this site came up with, as suggested in one of the answers on that question. We've been burned **a lot** trying to engage with these questions, so trust on these topics is difficult to come by, and very easy to lose.

Asking a question on this topic is skiing on the double black diamond slope of this site. Its possible to do, but unlikely to end well if you aren't *really* good at it.

Comment: Ok, so apparently I have choose the wrong topic for my first question, but as I have already stated I am genuinely interested in an authoritative answer and I'm not trying to troll or push any pro-Nazi or Holocaust denial agenda. I've revised my question in hope to get an answer, Thanks a lot for the clarification

Comment: @Viralk - Yes. I'd highly suggest for a new user to ask a few questions on other topics first. That'll help you learn what the site accepts in an environment where users are more inclined to be forgiving. Its a damn shame the bigots have driven us to these kinds of measures, but this is the world we live in.