# I added explanation of this question

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, asking-questions, reopen-closed, specific-question

https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/69367/what-could-have-the-carthagian-do-to-prevent-their-genocide

People think I want to "blame" Carthagian by asking those questions.

The issue is actually the opposite.

I am a businessman. I am often a victim of many things too. Like most people I used to blame the evil person that do it to me.

However, that's useless. Later I learn that it's more useful to ask what I could have done so I do it differently next time and don't be victim.

So instead of seeing what the aggressors could have done differently I tend to ask what the victims can do differently. The aggressors are often profited by their decisions. So it's pretty useless to ask why people stole my stuff or scam me. However, asking what could I have done to make sure I can't be scammed is more useful.

Comment: I guess it would help _this post_ to not just in essence repeat the now added _justification_ for your question on main in expanded form, but rephrase this to ask 'what's perceived as 'wrong' & how might I either fix this or (esp. if non-fixable) avoid the pitfalls for future questions"?

Answer (score 4):

#### The question is not currently framed as a historical question.

Thanks for posting on History Stack Exchange! Let's look at the question for a moment.

Here is the question:

> I read about how Rome mass murder carthagians and jews.
>
> I always wonder, short of fighting and killing romans and winning at it, what are the ways carthagians and people in ancient time, can avoid being killed?
>
> Some things I can think of is not flaunting wealth. The Carthagians paid off war compensation too early. They should have postponed paying it as much as possible. A lot of debt is good.
>
> It is possible that the romans want to kill Carthagians because they are rich.
>
> Another mistake would have been to try for peace too much. If Carthagians don't give weapons to e roman general, they would have been more able to defend themselves.
>
> Or do they?
>
> What could they have done?
>
> Note: Some people think that I wanted to "blame" Carthagian. The truth is the opposite. I am saddened that trade civilization like Carthagians are slaughtered. I wonder if they could have done this differently so anyone in their position could have survived.

First of all, it asserts a genocide but provides no sources for it. You say you "read about" this. Was this on Wikipedia? Did you find it in a high school history textbook? Did you read it in a journal or magazine? Is this from someone's blog?

Second, it asks us to speculate how this genocide (that we aren't even clear about) could have been avoided. That might be an interesting debate topic but isn't a question that we can answer using historical methods.

Third, the question, covering Jews and genocide, falls within our [controversial topics](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3684/21290) policy, in which these questions have a "hair-trigger for being put on hold". It must affirmatively demonstrate good faith and research or the question will be closed. It is true that most of its focus is on Carthaginians rather than Jews, but that does not change the fact that most of the question is, in fact, a victim-blaming question that is little more than, "Why don't victims of genocide fight back?". That's not something that we do here and not something we have any interest in doing. Asserting that a victim-blaming question is not one is the same as pointing to an elephant and calling it a duck. It doesn't work and it undermines the credibility of all its other claims.

If you could edit the question to add reliable sources (e.g. a history textbook, a journal article, etc.) and narrow down the question to something that can be reasonably answered, you may post on Meta or flag your question and we can undelete it so that it can go through the reopening process.

Comment: https://borgenproject.org/10-facts-genocide-punic-people/#:~:text=Three%20Punic%20Wars%20were%20fought,genocide%20of%20the%20Punic%20people.

There. There are many sources. Carthagian peace is actually referred many place

Answer (score 1):

The question still appears to be asking for opinions on how things hypothetically could have been done differently. There are certainly ways to fix that to be asking something more on-topic, but if at its core that's the question you want answered, well we don't do opinions or hypothetical alternate histories here. You're not going to be able to groom a horse to make it a cow.

If that's really really what you want to know, I'd suggest looking into writing this as a question on the [World Building SE site](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/). I don't think the current text would be ideal there, but something along the lines of "I'd like to build an alternate History where Rome didn't bother to destroy Carthage. How do I get there?" ought to work.